# Routing without using routconfig file in Asp.Net MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I faced these questions in one of my interview question which i was not able to answer..

How can we set routing in Mvc with  out using routconfig file ?

Mvc does not have statemanagement technique like viewstate as Asp.net , then how is the state managed in Mvc?...

How to pass data from controller to view and view to controller??
from controller to view we can pass using viewbag,viewdata, model binding...from view to controller also we can pass data with model binding,

are there any other options other than this?

Answer (score 0):

There is an option: You can use 
In ASP.NET, you can add the following configuration setting to applications in order to support routing:
      In you web.config file
       
        `<configuration>
         <system.webServer>
           <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
            <!-- more -->
           </modules>
         </system.webServer>
       </configuration>`

When `runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests` is `true`, a URL like `http://mysite/myapp/home` goes to ASP.NET, even though there is no .aspx, .mvc, or similar extension on the URL.
For more information Go to [MSDN ASP.NET Routing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx)